# Unable to start neo4j with both a homemade procedure including datastax cassandra driver and the graphaware framework

Tags: java, neo4j, cassandra, datastax, graphaware

I'm trying to write a **neo4j** Procedure which will write some datas to a **cassandra** cluster. I also need to have the **graphaware-framework** in my deployment, it' required by **graphawares** modules which I need.

I'm running **neo4j:3.5.4** with a docker-compose file. I have in my plugins folder for neo4j the jar *graphaware-server-community-all-3.5.4.53.jar*.

I have written the procedure responsible for writing data from **neo4j** to **cassandra** and tested it by itself, without loading the **graphaware-framework**.  It works fine.

But I can't start **neo4j** when both my procedure and the **framework** are in the plugins directory.

For debug purpose, I don't use the real procedure here but a simple counter procedure. It is sufficient to have the dependancy **com.datastax.cassandra** in the pom to trigger the problem.

---

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.neo4j.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>procedure-template</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Neo4j Procedure Template</name>
  <description>A template project for building a Neo4j Procedure</description>

  <properties>
    <neo4j.version>3.5.4</neo4j.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
      <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-harness</artifactId>
      <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
      <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

---

procedure

```
  @Procedure(value="test.ab.count")
  public Stream<CountResult> count(@Name("label") String label){
    Long count = (long) 0;
    ResourceIterator<Node> nodes = db.findNodes(Label.label(label));
    while(nodes.hasNext()){
      nodes.next();
      count += 1;
    }
    nodes.close();
    return Stream.of(new CountResult(count));
  }
```

with the CountResult object :

```
public class CountResult{
  public final static StringResult EMPTY = new StringResult(null);
  public final Long value;
  public CountResult(Long value){
    this.value=value;
  }
}
```

I package this with

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

The result i get when runniing my compose with both the procedure and the graphaware framework is :

```
Starting docker-n-test_neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc ... done
Attaching to docker-n-test_neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | command failed: the provided initial password was not set because existing Neo4j users were detected at `/var/lib/neo4j/data/dbms/auth`. Please remove the existing `auth` and `roles` files if you want to reset your database to only have a default user with the provided password.
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | Active database: graph.db
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | Directories in use:
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |   home:         /var/lib/neo4j
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |   config:       /var/lib/neo4j/conf
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |   logs:         /logs
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |   plugins:      /plugins
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |   import:       NOT SET
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |   data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |   certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |   run:          /var/lib/neo4j/run
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | Starting Neo4j.
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:22.257+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.discovery_listen_address
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:22.259+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: metrics.prometheus.endpoint
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:22.259+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.raft_advertised_address
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:22.260+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.raft_listen_address
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:22.260+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: ha.host.coordination
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:22.260+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: metrics.prometheus.enabled
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:22.260+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.transaction_advertised_address
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:22.260+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.discovery_advertised_address
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:22.260+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: ha.host.data
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:22.260+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.transaction_listen_address
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:22.269+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.5.4 ========
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:22.273+0000 INFO  Starting...
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:24.818+0000 INFO  GraphAware Runtime enabled, bootstrapping...
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:24.834+0000 INFO  GraphAware Runtime bootstrapped, starting the Runtime...
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:24.915+0000 INFO  Starting GraphAware...
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:24.916+0000 INFO  Loading module metadata...
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:24.953+0000 INFO  Module metadata loaded.
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:24.953+0000 INFO  Starting transaction-driven modules...
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:24.954+0000 INFO  Transaction-driven modules started.
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:24.954+0000 INFO  There are no timer-driven runtime modules. Not scheduling any tasks.
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:24.954+0000 INFO  GraphAware started.
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:24.954+0000 INFO  GraphAware Runtime automatically started.
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:29.590+0000 INFO  Shutting down GraphAware Runtime... 
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:29.590+0000 INFO  Terminating task scheduler...
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:29.591+0000 INFO  Task scheduler terminated successfully.
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:29.591+0000 INFO  GraphAware Runtime shut down.
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:29.629+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3566d527' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Implementing class". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3566d527' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Implementing class".
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3566d527' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Implementing class".
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:45)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:187)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:123)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:90)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:32)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3566d527' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Implementing class".
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:473)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:180)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  ... 3 more
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /data/databases
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:229)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:146)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityGraphFactory.newGraphDatabase(CommunityGraphFactory.java:41)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:90)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  ... 5 more
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures@4c1dc246' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Implementing class".
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:473)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:224)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  ... 9 more
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader$1.fetchNextOrNull(ProcedureJarLoader.java:166)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader$1.fetchNextOrNull(ProcedureJarLoader.java:138)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.collection.PrefetchingRawIterator.peek(PrefetchingRawIterator.java:50)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.collection.PrefetchingRawIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingRawIterator.java:36)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProcedures(ProcedureJarLoader.java:111)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProceduresFromDir(ProcedureJarLoader.java:85)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.start(Procedures.java:323)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc |  ... 11 more
neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc | 2019-07-01 11:20:29.632+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
docker-n-test_neo4j_1_ac35c08081cc exited with code 1
```

I can't figure a workaround to have this work, I'm also unsure what the problem is.

Comment: Did you ever make progress on this? I'm having the same problem. I suspect some class in my extension is polluting the classpath but not sure which one.

Comment: No, I was only running a few tests so I did not ry to get any further. I did the same tests with other databases drivers such as aerospike, mongodb, couchdb and postgresql and I ended using those.

Comment: I figured it out in my situation. I was creating a custom kernel extension for Neo4j. My jar file included dependencies already defined by the Neo4j classpath and when my plugin was loaded, it would redefine the class. I used the Gradle shadow plugin to relocate all of my dependent packages. https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/relocation/#automatically-relocating-dependencies.